# Como armazenar com segurança as credenciais AWS em uma aplicação Java?

Tags: java, segurança, amazon-aws

Tenho uma aplicação Java Desktop que é distribuída para os clientes.

Preciso, a partir de agora, enviar dados a partir desta aplicação para o Amazon S3. Para isso é necessário setar as credenciais AWS (*accessKeyId* e *secretKey*).

Dentre as opções possíveis na [documentação](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) (variáveis de ambiente, arquivo com os dados na máquina e arquivo de propriedades), a princípio nenhuma delas protege do próprio usuário da aplicação.

Já vi em outras linguagens o uso de criptografia RSA onde a chave para criptografar os dados era compilada na própria aplicação. Porém, o binário Java é facilmente "descompilado", o que inviabiliza este método.

**Neste cenário, como eu posso distribuir/armazenar as credenciais AWS com segurança para uso pela minha aplicação Java?**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma abordagem que não depende de credenciais da Amazon AWS direto no teu código, mas que utilize uma credencial gerada por você.

Crie um token exclusivo para cada cliente. Esse token será utilizado para que o cliente faça requests para um sistema seu. Você poderá revogar esse token do cliente a hora que você achar melhor, caso o contrato termine ou você suspeite que o token tenha vazado.

Digamos que o token gerado para o seu cliente X seja `d17ce9bd-98d2-4f98-add3-f0af4d49620b`. Com esse token em mãos, quando você precisar realizar o upload de algum arquivo para o Amazon S3, o aplicativo irá acessar uma URL, digamos, `https://meu.sistema.com.br/getUploadUrl?token=d17ce9bd-98d2-4f98-add3-f0af4d49620b` e o retorno desse request retornará um URL assinada da Amazon AWS para a qual o aplicativo deverá fazer upload, com uma validade determinada por você.

O código para gerar a URL será mais ou menos como o código abaixo:

```
System.out.println("Generating pre-signed URL.");
java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 60; // Adiciona 1 hora.
expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT); 
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Como a URL tem validade, se por acaso ela vazar, ela se tornará inútil após o prazo de expiração. Essa abordagem é interessante pois você não precisa distribuir as credenciais junto com seu código.

A documentação completa de como gerar essas URLs estão na documentação oficial da Amazon AWS, em [Upload an Object Using a Pre-Signed URL (AWS SDK for Java)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html)

Answer (score 1):

Como o @eduardosouza, também recomendo que não armazene estas chaves no seu código, ou mesmo em arquivos empacotados. Provavelmente sua aplicação não precisa se armazenar estas credenciais, mas a maneira mais segura depende de onde a sua aplicação está sendo executada:

- No EC2 ou Lambda basta atribuir uma Role do IAM para a instância ou função que automaticamente o SDK java encontra as credenciais temporárias através do serviço de metadados.
- Fora da AWS, como em sua maquina de desenvolvimento, pode usar as variáveis de ambiente para configurar o acesso.
- Mesmo se sua aplicação acessar a AWS em nome de um cliente, onde algumas aplicações armazenam chaves, é mais seguro utilizar Roles do IAM. Neste caso, considere o Amazon Cognito para gerenciar este processo de autenticação e autorização automaticamente.

Links relacionados na documentação:

[Roles do IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

[Credenciais no SDK Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)

[Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)